# C# result is fine when I am debugging, but I get errors when I start the .exe file

Tags: c#, debugging, logging

I work in C#, .Net 2.0.

When I debug my code everything works fine. However, when I create the exe, it isn't. I added a logger. Here is a piece of my code:

```
string[] dllFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(getAddinDllPath(), "Begin_*.dll");
foreach (string dllFile in dllFiles)
{
    Logger.Info("ThisMethod numberX");
    if (!dllFile.EndsWith("someString.dll", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dllFile);

        foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
        {
            Logger.Info("ThisMethod  numberY");
         ...............
```

The getAddinDllPath() method returns this:

```
addinDllPath = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(myDocuments, "Visual Studio 2005"), "Addins") + "\\";
```

When I debug my program, the text 'ThisMethod number Y' shows up multiple times in the log file.

When I create the exe and run it, the logger looks like this: ThisMethod numberX at the end. It never comes to "ThisMethod  numberY".

Why is that?

Here is my logger:

class Logger
    {
        private static string path = @"C:\Users\John\Documents\Projects\MyLogger.txt";

```
    public static string Path
    {
        get { return path; }
        set { path = value; }
    }

    public static void Info(string msg)
    {
        StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path);
        try
        {
            string logLine = System.String.Format(
                "{0:G}: {1}: {2}", System.DateTime.Now, @"INFO", msg);
            sw.WriteLine(logLine);
        }
        finally
        {
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Edit:
if dllFiles is empty, then everything is fine. But if the files are there, then the problem appears.

Edit 2:
The problem is in

```
Type type in assembly.GetTypes()
```

Has somebody an idea?

Comment: Add debug infos to your release version and try debugging this one.

Comment: Looks like your Logger class is not flushing the output.

Comment: Please use try catch so that you can catch the runtime exception.

Comment: @UweKeim It's the same version, the same code.

Comment: @leppie My logger class works fine when I debug the code, it writes "numberY" in the logger a few times. When I'm using the exe, it doesn't.

Comment: @Scree: Show us the code for your `Logger` class.

Comment: @leppie I updated the question.

Comment: Add a `sw.Flush()` after writing to it. The `finally` is never guaranteed to execute.

Comment: @leppie I added it. The result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have used

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllFile);
```

instead of

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dllFile);
```

Answer (score 3):

if `"somePath"` is relative to run directory then your exe might be scanning another directory => finding no .dll files => "ThisMethod  numberY" is not called.

If my guess is true - try specifying absolute path in `somePath`.

Comment: I updated my question. You can see now what the value of somePath is.

Comment: Then maybe you can add something like `Logger.Info(getAddinDllPath());` to your code before foreach-loop on dllFiles and compare the results for debug and release? If those are equal then most probably @leppie is right and you should add `sw.Flush();` after `sw.WriteLine(logLine);` in your logging class.

Comment: But the problem isn't the logger. I added the logger just to see where is the problem. My exe didn't work before the logger.

Comment: I added Logger.Info in getAddinDllPath and the path is correct:
C:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Addins\

Comment: Your code looks fine. Maybe there are some NTFS security issues like debug and release executables running with admin/non-admin privileges?

Answer (score 2):

Ensure `string dllFile in dllFiles` gives correct address of dll's & ends with string you mentioned in code and ensure log file is closed at the end. You will definitely see it.

Comment: I did and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `IndexOf >=0` not `EndsWith("someString.dll"`
sometimes it bugging
2. May be one of types defined or moved in other assembly / Look at msdn GetTypes where described exception